Enumerating integer pairs
Each integer can be enumerated using
$$a(n) = (-1)^{(n+1)} \times \lfloor \frac{(n+1)}{2} \rfloor$$
$$0, 1, -1, 2, -2 ...$$
(see https://oeis.org/A001057). Is there a known function $a(n)$ for generating each distinct integer pair in incremental Chebyshev distance? The first terms would be:
$$a(0) = (0, 0)$$
$$a(1) = (-1, -1)$$
$$a(2) = (-1, 0)$$
$$a(3) = (-1, 1)$$
$$a(4) = (0, -1)$$
$$a(5) = (0, 1)$$
$$a(6) = (1, -1)$$
$$a(7) = (1, 0)$$
$$a(8) = (1, 1)$$
though the order may vary from what I've written here. If so, is a function for integer n-tuples also known?

For context, I am plotting argand diagrams of tens of billions of order-four monic polynomials roots with integer coefficients, and would like to use this function to efficently retrieve coeffients of increasing Chebyshev distance (rather than my current method of taking cartesian products of arbitrary large integer ranges).

If you mean each pair in increasing Chebyshev distance from the origin, note that there are $(2n+1)^2$ points within $n$ spaces of the origin.  Probably the easiest way to order the points at a given distance is to start at one corner and go around the square.  I will start with the point at $(n,n)$ and go clockwise.  Given a point $(p,q)$ the Chebyshev distance from the origin is $d=\max (|p|,|q|)$  There are $(2d-1)^2$ points closer to the origin, so this square starts at $(2d-1)^2+1$ with the point $(d,d)$.  The lower right corner of the square is $(2d-1)^2+2d+1$ and corresponds to $(d,-d)$.  The lower left is $(2d-1)^2+4d+1$ and corresponds to $(-d-d)$.  The last point in the ring is $(2d-2)^2+8d=(2d+1)^2$ and corresponds to $(d-1,d)$

Is that also the case when using Chebyshev distance? To me it seems there are 4d(d+1) + 1 points at distance d from the origin in the 2d case
for context: 8d + floor(1/(d+1)) ) points are at distance d
